# how to use submit() method in this form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a little form that is used for registration. For submitting the form I've created a validating function with javascript. It looks like this..

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var company = document.getElementById('company').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var partnerID = document.getElementById('partner').value;
    var stdLicence = document.getElementById('stdlicense').value;

    var valid = validation(name, company, email, phone, partnerID, stdLicence);
    if (valid.isValid == true) {
        document.getElementById('submit').type = 'submit';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('errText').removeAttribute('hidden');
        document.getElementById('errText').value = valid.message;
    }
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
}
```

When all the fields are valid and user presses "Enter", it must submit the form and go to back end. As you can see in this code above , I'm changing the submit button type from button to "submit", when the form is valid. And this code is for pressing the "Enter" button.

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        validateForm();
        $("#sbmtForm").submit();
    }
});
```

When the form is invalid the enter button is reacting ok. But when the form is valid it's not submitting. Can anybody help me and say what's wrong with this code.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("#sbmtForm")[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the form submission -

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        validateForm();
        $("#sbmtForm").trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, but it didn't work for me. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Are you watching the browser's console when you run this? No errors?

Comment: Sure Jay, more than watching, I'm debugging too.

Comment: OK - just checking. Is it possible for you to setup a fiddle?

Comment: Actually the code is huge, with it's php and etc. So I think it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Can you just do the relevant parts? Or is it too interwoven?

Comment: Ok. I will try to pick some parts. Give me you JSFiddle address, cuz I haven't.

Comment: Just use jsfiddle.net, you don't need an account.